# How to extract an array in PHP from foreach loop?

Tags: php, arrays, foreach

I want to extract item 6 and item 9 from an array, I can get ingle values out using the [0] singled indexed row

But looking for the vector this does not work

```
$vector1 =  ($result['item3']['item6'][‘item9’]);
```

What is the best way to extract the arrays for item 6 and item 9 ?

```
Array
([0] => Array
    ([item1] => 123
     [item2] => 345
     [item3] => Array
        ([0] => Array
            ([item4] => Array
                ([item6] => 567
                 [item7] => 678
                 [item8] => Array
                    ([0] => Array
                        ([item9] => abc)
                    )
                )
            )
        )
    )
)
```

Comment: If it's a static array, then `$result[0]['item3'][0]['item4']['item6']` and `$result[0]['item3'][0]['item4']['item8'][0]['item9']`

Comment: ^ just barely beat me.

Comment: This is a rather inconsistent datastructure. I think you need to rethink it.

Answer (score 3):

```
$item6 =  $result[0]['item3'][0]['item4']['item6'];

$item9 =  $result[0]['item3'][0]['item4']['item8'][0]['item9'];
```